# How to get Android Studio Arctic Fox, "run all tests" to work?

Tags: android-studio, tdd, junit5

Before Arctic Fox I could run all the unit tests in my project by doing the following: Select a project. Open the context menu on a project, select menu item "run all test."

After Arctic Fox, this same action says something like "no test events."

How to get the "run all tests" feature working with Arctic Fox?

At the start of this TDD.Academy video we discuss this upgrade quirk along with the other Arctic Fox quirk about running JUnit and Roboelectric: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MxAjEqJ_LhM

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Patch two has fixed the problem.  With this patch you'll be able to again use "run tests" in the menubar.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem with Android Studio Arctic Fox. Even I created a Hello world project, the option in your screenshot does not work for me. I believe there was some change in the test configuration with gradle test runner  in android  4.3. Currently I will use the following as work around

1. Select one of the test class and right click to run it with Gradle Test Runner
2. Change the argument as `--tests "com.*"` in the current configuration to run all the test

[image]

Comment: Thanks Long Ranger! I'll try out your answer live during today's (episode 36) TDD.Academy livestream:  https://www.twitch.tv/tddacademy 
https://m.youtube.com/channel/UCU1U6oPscxzKd_IWAIOm60w

Comment: Long Ranger, this workaround did work. So I'm voting it up. Since it doesn't solve the problem of the context menu item "all tests", I'm going to wait and see if someone has the answer. As mentioned, we did talk about and use your solution during TDD.Academy's Episode 36, Android: Text Boxes and TDD #7: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ikQAmBNdRRo

Comment: BTW, I have a hunch that the solution is about adding the right gradel task which then executes like the workaround. But I don't know what gradel task to add.

Comment: Now that there have been a few Artic Fox versions released, that problem seems to be gone. I can now go back and use the "run all tests" configuration that comes as a default with Android Studio.

Comment: You can also use `--tests "*"` if there happen to be classes without `com` top-level domain name.